# How do I read variables from a file?

Tags: dual-boot, bash, xubuntu, windows-10

I've made a file with a Simple Linear Regression code that calculates the average of x and y values, and their standard deviations. Now, instead of inserting values myself (user input), I want to make a different file with values already stored in it and kind of "feed" them into my Linear Regression code. How do I go about doing so? (Bear in mind, I have Windows 10 so please do provide me with code that's compatible with my OS)

P.S. I'm very new to the Bash/Ubuntu environment so I'm not aware of almost everything used in the terminal.

Comment: It depends on how your script expects to obtain values - as arguments (positional parameters)? streamed via standard input? prompted for and read one-by-one via standard input? It would be easier to answer if you included at least the relevant portion of the script in your question

Answer (score 0):

data.txt:

```
1    2
3    4
5    6
```

script.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Import values form a file into an array using redirect.
array=($(<./data.txt))
echo "count: ${#array[@]}, data: ${array[@]}"

# We increase the counter i by the number of columns.
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i+=2)); do
     echo "X=${array[$i]}, Y=${array[(i+1)]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your variable file by this other software so that it looks like this:

   ```
   $ cat /tmp/foo.var   
   foo1="bar1"    
   foo2="bar2"   
   foo3="bar3"
   ```
2. From your bash script then source your variable file `/tmp/test.txt` like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash   
   source /tmp/foo.var   
   echo "$foo1"
   ```

Adapt the paths accordingly. Especially when using windows.